# Simple Python question: Why can't I assign a variable to a sorted list (in place)?

Tags: python

```
y = [1, 3, 2, 4]
x = y.sort()
print(x)
```

x is `None`. How come this sort of syntax works in, for example, Javascript, and not Python?

Comment: A function needs to return a value in order to use the returned value. Note what the docs for `sort` say.

Comment: Because `list.sort()` does not return the sorted array, that's happening in-place. It's just how python works/

Answer (score 6):

`sort` (and `reverse`) change the list in-place.

If you want, you can use `sorted`:

```py
x = sorted(y)
```

This is explained in the section [Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Here, `y.sort()` sorts y and can't be assigned to another variable.Here, you could  use `sorted()` like `x = sorted(y)` or:

```
x = [i for i in sorted(y)]
```

Or lets use a beautiful one-liner:

```
x = [y.pop(y.index(min(y))) for i in range(len(y))]
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `sort()` is an operation that is executed in place (it doesn't need to be re-assigned). It returns `None`, just like `append()`, `extend()`, and other list methods.